# How to perform replacements on a string using data from an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, replace

```py
#example input M x N matriz, basically being the matrix a list made up of sublists
new_matrix_aux = [['X', 'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'U1', 'L1', 'L2'], 
                  ['U1', 12,  3.0,  2.0, -1.0,  1.0,    0,    0], 
                  ['L1', 12,  2.0,  3.0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0], 
                  ['L2',  2, -2.0,  1.0,    0,    0,    0,  1.0]]

z_function = "Z = 1 * X1 + 4 * X2 + 0 * X3 + M * U1 + M * L1 + M * L2"
```

Here is the code, although it does not give the correct result since it begins by making the replacements using the row of column titles and the row titles, remember that the matrix can have any number of dimensions but it always respects that the first 2 columns are of the variable and the independent coefficient `B`

And the first row will always be the column titles.

```py
variables = new_matrix_aux[0][1:]  # Get the variables from the first row of the array
replacements = {var: 0 for var in variables}  # Initialize replacements with 0 for each variable

# Perform the replacements in the Z function
for col in range(1, len(new_matrix_aux[0])):
    column_name = new_matrix_aux[0][col]
    for row in range(1, len(new_matrix_aux)):
        variable = new_matrix_aux[row][0]
        value = new_matrix_aux[row][col]
        replacements[variable] = value

    z_function = z_function.replace(column_name, str(replacements[column_name]))

    print(f"Z_{column_name} = {z_function}")

    # Reset replacements to 0 for the next iteration
    for variable in replacements:
        replacements[variable] = 0
```

All variables from the first sublist that do not appear at the beginning of one of the following sublists must be replaced in the `"Z = 1 * X1 + 4 * X2 + 0 * X3 + M * U1 + M * L1 + M * L2 "` by `0`

The rest of the variables must be replaced by the values of the columns that indicate the variables of the `new_matrix_aux` matrix associated to the variables that are indicated in the rows of this matrix

In the `'X'` column are the names of the variables associated with the values of the rows, the `'B'` column is the independent term of this linear system, although we will not use it here because in the replacement in `Z`  has no independent terms, and the rest of the columns represent the variables

Iterating the columns of the `new_matrix_aux` matrix, and making the replacements in each iteration should print the following in the console

```py
"Z_B  = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 12 + M * 12 + M * 2"

"Z_X1 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 3.0 + M * 2.0 + M * -2.0"

"Z_X2 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 2.0 + M * 3.0 + M * 1.0"

"Z_X3 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * -1.0 + M * 0 + M * 0"

"Z_U1 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 1.0 + M * 0 + M * 0"

"Z_L1 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 1.0 + M * 0"

"Z_L2 = 1 * 0 + 4 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0 + M * 1.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have converted the list to a numpy array. If your matrices are large, you can further improve performance. This is a quick brute force kind of solution

```py
import numpy as np

new_matrix_aux = [['X', 'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'U1', 'L1', 'L2'], 
                  ['U1', 12,  3.0,  2.0, -1.0,  1.0,    0,    0], 
                  ['L1', 12,  2.0,  3.0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0], 
                  ['L2',  2, -2.0,  1.0,    0,    0,    0,  1.0]]

z_function = "Z = 1 * X1 + 4 * X2 + 0 * X3 + M * U1 + M * L1 + M * L2"

new_matrix_aux_np=np.array(new_matrix_aux)

for j in range(len(new_matrix_aux_np[0,1:])):
    z=z_function
    for i in range(len(new_matrix_aux_np[1:,0])):
        if(new_matrix_aux_np[i+1,0] in new_matrix_aux_np[0,1:]):
            z=z.replace(new_matrix_aux_np[i+1,0], new_matrix_aux_np[i+1,j+1])
    for k in range(len(new_matrix_aux_np[0,1:])):
        if(new_matrix_aux_np[0, k+1] in z):
            z=z.replace(new_matrix_aux_np[0, k+1], '0')
    z=z.replace(z[0], z[0]+'_'+new_matrix_aux_np[0,j+1])
    print(f'"{z}"')
```